# In post_meta after "add new" how to redirect to list page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using register_post_type to create post_meta so in "add new" functionality after adding and publish it is redirecting to "edit page". How I can redirect it to list page after publish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `redirect_post_location` action hook to redirect your post type to location or url you need after editing or publishing.

```
function custom_redirect($location) {

    global $post_type;

    if ($post_type == 'your post type here') {
        $location   = admin_url('edit.php?post_type=' . $post_type);
    }

    return $location;
}

add_action( 'redirect_post_location', 'custom_redirect');
```

It checks for your post type and create the url to the list page of your post type and set new redirect locations.

Hope this helps you :-)